# Spotfire axis restriction

Tags: spotfire, tibco

I have 4 columns: **Companies, Products, Sales and Sales Growth**.

I need to create a cross table with Companies in Horizontal axis, Products in Vertical axis and Sales Growth in cell values. But I need to show **only top 10 products (by sum of sales) and top 10 companies (by sum of sales as well)** in my vizualisation and I don't know how to restrict products and companies in my axisses.

I tried to calculate new ranking column which I would use as a condition in axis definition, but the result of my calculation is completely wrong and I really don't know what's wrong, it seemed so simple.

`DenseRank([Company],"desc",sum([Sales]))`

Next options are to use Show/Hide Items or Data limitation, but I didn't manage to set it correctly.

Could you please give me some advice how to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The closest example I have is limiting to the top Nth products per company.

Using show/hide with an expression of `Max(DenseRank(Sum([Sales]) OVER (Intersect([Companies],[Product])),"desc",[Companies]))`